# How to change directory in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am very new to scripting, can anybody tell how can I switch to directory in `bash`.

I have tried to do like this

```
-bash-4.2$ cd /c
```

and `cd c` but nothing works!

Comment: is the folder available in the directory, `cd c` or `cd c/` should do it!

Comment: go to http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php and start from there

Comment: @lnian yeah it is available dont know why this not working

Comment: @priyankasharma How about `ls -l /c` or whatever the path to your dir is?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing works"?  What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if you have any directories in your current path!
You can check that by `ls -lrt` which lists the files and directories in your current path.

If there are no directories, create one using `mkdir c` and then do `cd c`

Also you can navigate to your previous directory by using `cd -` and your home directory by doing a `cd ~`

Comment: there is c directory when I do ls -lrt but when i try to switch then it says no such file or directory

Comment: are you on windows or linux? can you do a quick `uname -a` ?

Comment: linux its is i checked

Comment: Can you run a command called `pwd` in your shell?  and also paste output of a `ls -lrt` ?

Comment: @priyankasharma Are you aware that Linux file systems are case sensitive?  I.e. if the directory is called `C`, you need to use `cd C` to change to it.

Comment: @priyankasharma can you please copy and paste the output you get by running those commands in the original question? It will help to address the problem better

Comment: ohk its case sensitive  so now its changed and one thing if I want to go inside the folder inside c then again should I use cd  *name of folder*?

Comment: yes! `cd name_of_folder`